# Set-up a Child Table that always has the same number of rows as the Parent table?

Tags: html, mysql

I was wondering if there is any way to set-up the relationship between a Child and Parent table where the Child Table always has the same number of rows as the Parent Table.

**An Example** : The Parent table acts as a 'Master-list' or 'Dictionary' for ingredients used in a kitchen, within the table it would have multiple columns that store information on the ingredient such as - a unique ID, ingredient name, a supplier/brand, a unit of measurement, etc.

The Child table represents different locations where ingredients are stored, (*Different Branches*) - The Child Table would probably only have 2 columns being the ingredient's unique ID and Quantity. The child table needs to contain the same number of rows as Parent table. If a new entry is created in the Parent Table then the Child table should also have the new entry with Quantity = 0.

**Alternative Solution** : In the case that this isn't possible, What I currently have in mind in order to achieve this would be how I handle the forms, If a new entry into the Parent table is made it would also have code to insert the new entry into the existing Child tables, Though this would mean every-time there is a new location (*new child table*)
I could also create a sort of form that checks if the Parent table and a specific Child table has the same number of Rows.

Thank you for your time and input.

Comment: Why not just adding the columns to the first table?

Comment: You have a 1-1 relationship, you don't want to store it in two different tables. Why not just add column quantity to the parent table ?

Comment: @GMB I don't want to store the quantity column in the Parent table because I have multiple locations, So there would only be One Parent table for multiple Child Tables.
And I want to know exactly how much of a ingredient is at a specific location

Comment: You said : *The child table needs to contain the same number of rows as Parent table.*

Comment: @GMB - Yes so if the parent table has 20 different ingredients, then each Child table should have 20 different ingredients even if the quantity is 0. (Which I know is really odd because what's the point of storing all the 0 values - but it's an example :/ )

Comment: So you mean that you are planning to create a child table for each location ?

Comment: @GMB yup, each Child Table represents a Location, The parent table contains detailed information on a unique item, the Child Table stores the quantity available at each location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are planning to create a child table for each location that will store the ingredients quantity. This will generate a situation where multiple tables havea a 1-1 relationship with the ingredients table. This normalization is not adapted to your use case.

Consider the following alternative design :

- table `ingredients` stores the ingredients masterdata
- table `locations` lists the different locations
- table `ingredients_locations` stores the quantity of each product in each location : it has a foreign key that references the ingredient id, and another one towards the location id

Comment: Should I add an index number (auto_increment) number for ingredients_locations table? Like is there any value in having an index number like this?